# Is it possible to convert BUTTON_POSITIVE to a circular progress bar?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

I have an alert dialog and I want when the user clicks on the `BUTTON_POSITIVE` replace it with a circular progress bar during did something, Is it possible or not possible?

Comment: Why are you not using Custom Dialog box with custom layout, where you can handle these types of things??

Comment: Yes I know but I asked if is it possible without custom dialog, If not, Then I'll create custom dialog

Comment: Alert Dialog has inbuilt layout file for handling title,message and buttons, if its possible to override inbuilt layout for alert dialog then you will do this, otherwise you need a custom dialog for these things.

Comment: @DeePanShu Okay , Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.